# Using Modern IFileDialog Open/Save dialog with Delphi 7 apps under Win10/11

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I would like to modernize the GUI of my Delphi 7 App, I have already .manifest file and it looks quite good, but the Fileopen dialogs are terrible. How the make them modern?

I am using this code at the moment.
What would it require to use e.g. IFileOpenDialog instead, how to compile the header for that, or any tweaks to dialogs.pas ?

```
FileOpenDialog := TOpenDialog.create(parent);
FileOpenDialog.DefaultExt := '*.x';
FileOpenDialog.Filter := 'my|*.x|Text File (CSV)|*.csv'; 
FileOpenDialog.options := [ofHideReadOnly,ofFileMustExist  ,ofNoChangeDir,ofPathMustExist   ];
if FileOpenDialog.Execute then begin
    // do my tricks with FileOpenDialog.filename
    FormUpdate;
end;
```

The following example code of IFileDialog  cannot be compiled with D7:

```
var
  FolderDialog : IFileDialog;
  hr: HRESULT;
  IResult: IShellItem;
  FileName: PChar;
  Settings: DWORD;
begin
  if Win32MajorVersion >= 6 then
    begin
      hr := CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog,
                   nil,
                   CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                   IFileDialog,
                   FolderDialog);

      if hr = S_OK then
        begin
          FolderDialog.SetOkButtonLabel(PChar('Select'));
          FolderDialog.SetTitle(PChar('Select a Directory'));

          hr := FolderDialog.Show(Handle);
          if hr = S_OK then
            begin
              hr := FolderDialog.GetResult(IResult);

              if hr = S_OK then
                begin
                  IResult.GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH,FileName);
                  ConfigPathEdit.Text := FileName;
                end;
            end;
        end;
    end;
```

Comment: Delphi 7 doesn't support the new dialogs out of the box. If you don't find any 3rd party controls you are probably on your own implementing all what it needs. You may consider upgrading your Delphi version.

Comment: Here's a great place to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog

Comment: It's quite easy to patch the VCL so that the new dialogs are shown, even with the GetOpenFileName based wrappers. However, it's better to use IFileDialog because it supports arbitrary length multi select dialogs.

Comment: I gave up with the Windows dialogue and ended up doing my own, in a form, where I can have user-configurable shortcut buttons and autocomplete recursive search. It's not difficult to do.

Comment: Is there any example how to use iFileDialog with Delphi7 ?

Comment: @Tom Sure. Welcome to StackOverflow - it also supports [searching for i.e. `iFileDialog [Delphi]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iFileDialog+%5BDelphi%5D), which then has [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11260116/4299358) as one of its results.

Comment: @AmigoJack: But of course, `IFileDialog` isn't defined in the Delphi 7's Win32 units.

Comment: Thanks I was looking for it earlier but failed to compile; How can I define IFileDialog I am getting [Error] Undeclared identifier: 'IFileDialog'

Comment: `IFileDialog` is an interface that modern Delphi versions define in `Winapi.ShlObj` unit. Dehlpi 7 does not have such unit. But as far as I remember all Win API function relate to Shell in Delphi 7 are declared in `Shell32.pas` unit or something similar. So I recommend you start looking there.

Comment: Correction the unit you need to be looking into is `ShellAPI.pas`

Comment: You may also want to check [Delphi 7 and Vista/Windows 7 common dialogs - events do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1894318/3636228) which has several answers on how to access modern open dialogs from Delphi 7. I haven't tested any of them so they might or may not work.

Comment: @SilverWarior: The OP probably won't find `IFileDialog` in their `ShellAPI.pas`. `IFileDialog` was introduced in Windows Vista, IIRC, in 2007. Interface declarations introduced in 2007 are rarely available in Delphi 7 from 2002.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this one, I tested it with D7.

```
// uses commdlg
function OpenSaveFileDialog(      Parent: TWinControl;
                            const DefExt,Filter,InitialDir,Title: string;
                              var FileName: string;
                                  MustExist,OverwritePrompt,NoChangeDir,DoOpen: Boolean): Boolean;
     var ofn: TOpenFileName;
         szFile: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
   begin
         Result := False;
         FillChar(ofn, SizeOf(TOpenFileName), 0);
         with ofn do
           begin
           lStructSize := SizeOf(TOpenFileName);
           hwndOwner := Parent.Handle;
           lpstrFile := szFile;
           nMaxFile := SizeOf(szFile);

           if (Title <> '') then
              lpstrTitle := PChar(Title);

           if (InitialDir <> '') then
              lpstrInitialDir := PChar(InitialDir);

           StrPCopy(lpstrFile, FileName);
           lpstrFilter := PChar(StringReplace(Filter, '|', #0,[rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase])+#0#0);

           if DefExt <> '' then
              lpstrDefExt := PChar(DefExt);
           end;

         if MustExist then
            ofn.Flags := ofn.Flags or OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

         if OverwritePrompt then
            ofn.Flags := ofn.Flags or OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT;

         if NoChangeDir then
            ofn.Flags := ofn.Flags or OFN_NOCHANGEDIR;

         if DoOpen
            then begin
                 if GetOpenFileName(ofn) then
                    begin
                    Result := True;
                    FileName := StrPas(szFile);
                    end;
                 end
            else begin
                 if GetSaveFileName(ofn) then
                    begin
                    Result := True;
                    FileName := StrPas(szFile);
                    end;
                 end;
    end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
      VAR FilSelez : String;
    begin
          If OpenSaveFileDialog(Form1,'','*.*','c:\windows','',FilSelez,False,False,True,True) Then
             Edit1.Text := FilSelez;
    end;
```

Comment: The OP specifically asks how to use the Vista+ file dialogs, but this answer explains a way to use the old, pre-Vista, file dialogs. **Update:** I suppose the system will display a Vista dialog box even though you use the old API, right? If so, you may want to make that explicit in this (almost code-only) answer.

Comment: Yes, the most recent dialog is displayed, with D7 it can be seen using the "OpenDialog" component at the same time

Comment: Excellent working code without questions asked why don't you upgrade your D7 :D

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `IFileDialog` interface you can also just modify Delphi's 7 `Dialogs.pas` file to display the "modern" dialogs.
First make a backup copy of the `Dialogs.pas` file in the `Source\VCL` folder under the Delphi installation directory. Then search the file for the term `OFN_ENABLEHOOK`. The complete line should be `Flags := OFN_ENABLEHOOK;`. Comment out the line. Add a new line `Flags := 0;` directly below.
Now search for the term `OFN_ENABLETEMPLATE`. Two lines above this should be an `if Template <> nil then` statement. Comment out this statement and all following ones up to and including `hWndOwner := Application.Handle;` and add the line `hWndOwner := Screen.ActiveForm.Handle;`.

Now make sure to replace the precompiled units `Dialogs.dcu` in the `Lib` and `SLib` directory under the Delphi installation directory with newly compiled `Dialogs.dcu` containing the changes. In the `Lib` directory you store a version without debug information, while the `SLib` directory contains a version with debug information. Make backup copies of the files before replacing them.

Please take note that the instructions given above only apply to Delphi 7. Furthermore, the code disables event handling for the common dialog components.